# display photos from facebook with javascript api?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I want to display photos from one of my facebook albums on my webpage with the javascript api.
I can read the album names with the below code, but how can I then display the photos of one of the albums?

```
FB.api('/myfacebookid/albums', function(response) {

    var ul = document.getElementById('albums');
    for (var i=0, l=response.data.length; i<l; i++) {
      var
        album = response.data[i],
        li = document.createElement('li'),
        a = document.createElement('a');
      a.innerHTML = album.name;
      a.href = album.link;
      li.appendChild(a);
      ul.appendChild(li);
    }
  });
```

Any input appreciated, thanks!

OK, now I have this code instead:

```
    FB.api('/142461229141170/albums?fields=id,name', function(response) {
     if (response && response.data && response.data.length){
         console.log(response)

  for (var i=0; i<response.data.length; i++) {
    var album = response.data[i];

    if (album.name == 'Profile Pictures'){

      FB.api('/'+album.id+'/photos', function(photos){
        if (photos && photos.data && photos.data.length){
          for (var j=0; j<photos.data.length; j++){
            var photo = photos.data[j];
            // photo.picture contain the link to picture
            var image = document.createElement('img');
            image.src = photo.picture;
            $('#foton').append(image);
          }
        }
      });

      break;
    }
  }
   }
});
```

I guess Im doing something wrong..still! This is displaying the photos from the Profile Pictures album but I had to change it to $('#foton').append(image); . If I look at the log it gets 4 objects.

If I change to a different album eg - Manmade Photos or Cover Photos it stops working.

And also if I change the userId from above(the above is a PAGE id) to my personal facebook id then it stops working aswell.

Im really trying to understand how this works, because I also want to get the feed and some other stuff after this, and I guess that it works the same way as this? Thanks a lot, guys!

Answer (score 8):

This can be done by issuing Graph API request to `photos` connection of `album`:

```
FB.api('/me/albums?fields=id,name', function(response) {
  for (var i=0; i<response.data.length; i++) {
    var album = response.data[i];
    if (album.name == 'Profile Pictures'){

      FB.api('/'+album.id+'/photos', function(photos){
        if (photos && photos.data && photos.data.length){
          for (var j=0; j<photos.data.length; j++){
            var photo = photos.data[j];
            // photo.picture contain the link to picture
            var image = document.createElement('img');
            image.src = photo.picture;
            document.body.appendChild(image);
          }
        }
      });

      break;
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: I've just had something similar close at hand, otherwise it would end up something like your answer ;)

Comment: Thanks, Juicy.
I tested with the above, but I get an error:
TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'response.data.length')

Comment: @Claes, This is generally means that list of albums wasn't returned by first `FB.api` call. Add the check similar to one I've used in second call to avoid this error. Dig into `response` object to undertand why albums wasn't returned something like `console.log(response)` may help.

Answer (score 4):

You use the graph to do it... all you need is the `album.id` from above, and then you make a call to the graph to get the photos.  I passed `fields=pictures` to tell facebook to only return the picture links.  You can omit this parameter and it will bring you a whole bunch of stuff back.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/<album.id>/photos?fields=picture
```

The list of all of the fields can be found here [Album - Graph API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/album/)

Comment: Ok, I have tested in the Graph explorer with :
 FB.api('/me/albums?fields=id,name' and 
FB.api('/'+album.id+'/photos' and it returns the right content.
So why Im I getting the error: TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'response.data.length'), I simply dont understand?

Comment: Add an extra section in your question that shows the code you are talking about... what is `response.data`