# Posting a photo to a page's album which I am NOT an admin of?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

Before I even post any code or get too specific with my problem. Is it even possible for an app to post to a page's photo album when the logged in user is not the admin of the page?

> **An example use to help understand the task:**
>
> Say my page was promoting a t-shirt I'm selling. I'd like to allow the
> public to upload photos of themselves wearing my t-shirt to the
> facebook page. Then I'd like to display these photos on my t-shirt
> company website in a gallery. Is this possible using the graph API and/or FQL?

I'm just hoping I'm not on a wild goose chase! Does anybody know or has anybody achieved this?

Note: I'm limited to using JavaScript so any hard-coded access tokens are out of the question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9602086/display-photos-from-facebook-with-javascript-api

Comment: Yeah, that doesn't answer the question at all.

Comment: Does anybody know if this is possible in theory...?